# WebCam: Switch on and of or or keep on

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam

Good day,

I wasn't sure if I should post this on the software or hardware stack; I apologize in advance if this is an invalid question.

I wrote a little application that I am using to make time lapse videos - currently it only takes the pictures using a webcam. I know there are already a few available for download, but none of them did 100% what I wanted, and some of them were a little buggy, so I decided I'd rather create my own.

The interval at which the pictures are taken can be configured anywhere from 5 seconds up. Version 1.x would activate the camera and keep it on while in "Time Lapse Mode" and save images to disc at the specified intervals. This approach proved to be very memory intensive - understandably, in retrospect.

I decided to start from scratch - Version 2.x. This version would keep the camera off and only switch it on when it needed to take a picture, and switch it off again. This approach proved much more efficient. The reason for the minimum limit of 5 second intervals is because the camera takes about 1 second to switch on and then roughly the same amount of time to switch off. Perhaps in the future I could change it to keep the camera on when the `interval < 5`. For now, however, for what I actually want to use it, this will do perfectly.

When I was little we, as children, were told that switching an incandescent bulb on and off and on and off is not good for the bulb - according to a colleague of mine, reliable in that field, this is true.

This got me thinking. Could it be harmful to my webcam if I switch it on and off at, say, 10 second intervals for, let's say, a day or two? And how would switching on and off compare to keeping the device on for a few days? I don't understand what happens on a hardware level so I can't say.

I suppose I have a couple of options:

- Switch the application on and off as required to take the pictures. This could result in the camera being switched a few thousand times a day.
- Keep the camera on. This could mean the camera might be active for very long periods of time. What if I want to create a time lapse video over a month? Or even a year? Not to mention the memory problem.
- Switch between the two modes. When `interval < 2 minutes ? keep on : switch`. This seems like the best of both worlds but now I'm faced with the memory problem when `interval < 2 minutes`

Thank you in advance for any and all comments and suggestions - much appreciated.

Kind regards,
me.

Comment: switching the camera on and off will have no affect on it's lifespan.

Comment: how about keeping it on for long periods of time? could that affect its lifespan?

Comment: well that really depends on the camera but for something as low powered as a webcam you should be able to run it for many many years before it begins to fail.

Comment: if I may ask.. Why is your program so memory intensive? how are you grabbing frames from the web cam?

Comment: @Axis: i'm using, probably, the most common webcam library on the internet. all the research i have done on the subject pointed to the same solution - i mean, without writing all the code myself. all i'm really doing is handling an event. from there i can paint the image to an imagebox of save it to disc or both. i'm not sure if i answered your question

Comment: moved my comments to an answer

Answer (score 1):

**Could it be harmful to my webcam if I switch it on and off at, say, 10 second intervals for, let's say, a day or two?**
Switching the camera on and off will have no affect on it's lifespan.

**How about keeping it on for long periods of time?**
Well that really depends on the camera but for something as low powered as a webcam you should be able to run it for many many years before it begins to fail.

Not sure how you are getting frames from your camera but it should not be extremely memory intensive. Using [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) you can pretty simply grab frames from you camera. [Tutorial](http://irslab.blogspot.com/2010/07/webcam-using-aforgenet-part-ii.html) If you could post your code I could better see how to point you in the direction of optimizing it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. AForge.NET certainly looks interesting - I definitely want to check that out sometime; Version 3 ;) As for posting my code, I appreciate your offer but I couldn't expect something like that, the effort and the time, from anyone.